# a static class method not returning the right value

Tags: c#

The idea of the program is to output the department which has the biggest salary combined by every person working in that department.
so I have my program.cs:

```
string print = string.Empty;
            int n = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            for(int a = 0; a < n; a++)
            {
                string input = Console.ReadLine();
                List<string> inputs = input.Split(" ").ToList();
                if(inputs[4].Contains("@"))
                {
                    Employee info = new Employee(inputs[0], double.Parse(inputs[1]), inputs[2], inputs[3], inputs[4], int.Parse(inputs[5]));
                    print = info.ToString();
                }
                else
                {
                    Employee info = new Employee(inputs[0], double.Parse(inputs[1]), inputs[2], inputs[3], "n/a", int.Parse(inputs[4]));
                    print = info.ToString();
                }
                Employee.Calculation(inputs[3], double.Parse(inputs[1]));
            }
            Console.WriteLine(print);
```

and part of my Employee.cs, which is the inportant one:

```
public static void Calculation(string department, double salary)
        {

            Dictionary<string, double> data = new Dictionary<string, double>();
            if (data.ContainsKey(department))
            {
                data[department] += salary;
            }
            else
            {
                data.Add(department, salary);
            }
            foreach (KeyValuePair<string, double> info in data)
            {
                if (info.Value > biggestSalary)
                {
                    biggestSalary = info.Value;
                    toReturn = info.Key;
                }
            }

        }
        public override string ToString()
        {
            string line1 = "Highest average salary: " + toReturn;
            return line1;


        }
```

with this input:

```
4
Pesho 120000 Dev Daskalo pesho@abv.bg 28
Toncho 333333.33 Manager Marketing 33
Ivan 15000 ProjectLeader Development ivan@ivan.com 40
Gosho 130033333 Freeloader Nowhere 18
```

the last line is ignored for some reason when I debugged it and it returns the 2nd biggest salary - in department "Marketing".
with this input:

```
6
Stanimir 496.37 Temp Coding stancho@yahoo.com 50
Yovcho 610.13 Manager Sales 33
Toshko 609.99 Manager Sales toshko@abv.bg 44
Venci 0.02 Director BeerDrinking beer@beer.br 23
Andrei 700.00 Director Coding 45
Popeye 13.3333 Sailor SpinachGroup popeye@pop.ey 67
```

i get "Coding" instead of "Sales". When you combine the 2 people working "Coding" you get  700 + 496 = 1196. When you combine the 2 people working in "Sales" you get 609 + 610 = 1219 and then the output should be "Highest average salary: Sales", but instead the output is  "Highest average salary: Coding";

Comment: if I understand the problem statement, your trying to get the department name which has the highest paying employee?. if that is the case, can you show the details of variable 'biggestSalary' declared and its scope?

Comment: What about using a debugger?

Comment: @Immanuel not exactly. If 1 person earns 900 in Marketing for example. And 1 person in Coding earns 800 + another person in coding earns 200, that makes 1000, which is the thing that should be printed.

Comment: in that case, I think @SBFrancies already answered. this declaration Dictionary<string, double> data = new Dictionary<string, double>(); should be at class level and not at method level.

Comment: You use `Employee info = new Employee(...)` but you never use that `info`, apart from a `print = info.ToString();` which you keep overwriting until you write out the last value

Comment: Better structure : first read all employees into a `List<Employee>` and only *then* start calculating. And please do not misuse employee-specific ToString to get the result of a calculation

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new dictionary every time the `Calculation` method is called.

```
Dictionary<string, double> data = new Dictionary<string, double>();


// The first block is never called as the Dictionary never contains anything at this point. The else block always runs.    
if (data.ContainsKey(department))
{
    data[department] += salary;
}
else
{
    data.Add(department, salary);
}
```

There is therefore only ever one value in the dictionary for the one employee that that is meant to be added.

Since an employee with the Coding department has the highest individual value, that is the department that is returned.

Without commenting on the other aspects of the code the way to avoid this issue is to create the Dictionary first outside of the Calculation method.

Comment: and how do I create the dictionary outside of the calculation method?

Comment: You can create it as a static property on the class - if you don't want to change your code structure as has been suggested elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you would add `Employee` to the `List<Employee>`, finding this value using LINQ would look like

```cs
public class Employee
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Dept { get; set; }
    public decimal Salary { get; set; }

}

// preload
var empList = new List<Employee>(); 
empList.Add(new Employee(){Name = "A", Salary = 10, Dept = "Sales" });
empList.Add(new Employee(){Name = "B", Salary = 10, Dept = "Coding" });
empList.Add(new Employee(){Name = "C", Salary = 30, Dept = "Sales" });
empList.Add(new Employee(){Name = "D", Salary = 20, Dept = "Coding" });
                
// execute
var topItem =  empList.GroupBy(_ => _.Dept)
    .Select(g => new { D = g.First().Dept, TS = g.Sum(s => s.Salary)})
    .OrderByDescending(item => item.TS)
    .First();

Console.WriteLine($"The department '{topItem.D}' has biggest salary: '{topItem.TS}'");
```

> The department 'Sales' has biggest salary: '40'

Returning to the point that your code structure has a role in your problem. Even if you calculate this in the loop, you still want to accumulate your employees on the class/application scope variable, so you have continuous access to it.

As applicable to your case, your `Employee info = new Employee` seem not added to any list. And `Employee.Calculation` does not use any program-lever variable, which would keep the state.

If I wanted to keep this structure, the one you have, I could declare your class like

```cs
public class Employee
{

    private static List<Employee> _empList = new List<Employee>(); 

    // your constructor
    public Employee (........)
    {
        // Assign your properties here
        _empList.Add(this);
    }


    // And your `Employee.Calculation` would lose any parameters and look like this 
    public static void Calculation()
    {
        var topItem =  _empList.GroupBy(_ => _.Dept).......
        
        Console.WriteLine($"The department '{topItem.D}' has biggest salary: '{topItem.TS}'");
    }
}
```

^^^ that is if I really wanted to fix the issue but keep the structure you have already